# Insert decimal value into Currency Access field

Tags: c#, ms-access, type-conversion

**Short background:** I am replacing an outdated, Visual Based based program with a C#-based one. With the program comes an Access (JET) based database which is already in use. For now, I want to connect to the current database for practical reasons. However in the foreseeable future I'd like to replace it with SQL Server.

**Question:** The database stores financial information using the Access 'Currency' datatype. In C#, I use 'Decimal' to represent financial information. Naturally, I get an error when I try an INSERT or UPDATE-query to store the Decimal in the Currency-field (actually, I get an error once and with it, it automatically changes the datatype of that specific record to Decimal). I'm not sure what the best way to solve this problem is:

1. Transform the Decimal into Currency in my program and inserting it after. Is this even possible (C# says the values from the field are of the DBNull-type since it doesn't know Currency)? If yes, how do I do this?
2. Change the datatype of the field into Decimal. *Will I risk corrupting financial information when I do this?*
3. Any other/better suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

---

The exact error message:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [07006] 
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access-stuurprogramma]Inbreuk op kenmerk van beperkt gegevenstype
```

It's Dutch and translates to `Restricted data type attribute violation`

My UPDATE code:

```
public Boolean setFuelCosts(int rentID, Decimal fuelcosts)
        {
            string conString = lem2;
            string queryString = "UPDATE rental SET fuel = ? WHERE rentid = ?";
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);
            command.Parameters.Add("@fuel", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = fuelcosts;
            command.Parameters.Add("@rentid", OdbcType.Int).Value = rentID;
            return factory.executeUpdateCommand(conString, command);
        }

public Boolean executeUpdateCommand(String conString, OdbcCommand command)
        {
            bool result = false;
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    connection.Open();
                    int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    result = (i >= 1);
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.StackTrace);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: An example of your code where you try to insert the values and the exact error message received will be of great help here (Access version?)

Comment: Have you tried sending the variable as type : OleDbType.Currency?

Comment: I've added both my code and the error message. Access version is 97 (like I said, outdated).
@ OmerBTW: I'm using Odbc, so I'm afraid that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be a limitation of the Access ODBC driver when dealing with `Currency` fields using `System.Data.Odbc` in .NET. An OdbcDataReader will *return* those fields as `System.Decimal` (if the value is not NULL), but `System.Data.Odbc` apparently won't accept a `System.Decimal` parameter for a `Currency` field.

As a workaround you could replace

```csharp
command.Parameters.Add("@fuel", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = fuelcosts;
```

with

```csharp
command.Parameters.Add("@fuel", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = fuelcosts.ToString("0.0000");
```

I just tested this from C# 2010 against an Access 2000 database file and it worked for me.

Comment: Further testing has revealed that `InvariantCulture` can actually cause the update to fail in some circumstances, so I have removed it from the answer.

Comment: I know this question (and the answer) is pretty old but if someone has the case and he uses Dapper, here is the syntax :

`connection.Execute(queryString, new { 
   fuel = new DbString { Value = fuelcosts.ToString("0.000"), Length = 50 },
   id = rentID
});`